# Strange behaviour in item recommendation with MyMediaLite

Tags: c#, command-line, recommendation-engine

I'm working with the MyMediaLite's item recommendation tool and I'm trying to understand how can I do in order to generate a prediction file which consists only of test set's items.
Actually with the default options (--overlap-items) it generates a prediction file which contains both items that are present in the test set and someone which aren't present in it. This is really annoying simply because I need to obtain correct recommendation in order to generate the metrics for my recommender (I use an external tool in order to generate the metrics).
So I've tried the option "--in-test-items" which should use as candidate items only those present in the test set, but this is not the result that I obtain. Actually I'm working with the movielens 100k dataset which I've binarized following a specific strategy: I've assigned 1 to items which have as rating 4 or 5, otherwise 0.

I want to report here the command that I use in order to produce the recommendation in a implicit feedback situation(supposing that I'm trying to execute the test on the first split of the dataset):

item_recommendation --training-file=u1.base --test-file=u1.test --prediction-file=u1.mml_res --in-test-items --recommender=ItemKNN --predict-items-number=10

There is something incorrect in this command? Do I have to fix something?

Thank you in advance.

Alessandro Suglia

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered in this e-mail thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mymedialite/Sm6RXehqrYE